# Ajax.BeginForm does not output form action after give actionName and controllerName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

very standard code

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Subscriber", null, 
                        new AjaxOptions 
                                 { 
                                  OnBegin   = "ajaxBegin", 
                                  OnFailure = "ajaxFailure", 
                                  OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess" 
                                 },
                                 new{id = "ajax1121"})
                       {
                       }
```

its output `<form action="" ...>`  action is empty !! I tried changing the code with another overload by removing ajaxoptions etc, no use

and most amazing, same code works at another area. I even tried copying `_ViewStart.cshtml` and `Web.config` files from the area to problem area, still not working. The area got problem name `Mail`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, no client side. Instead of putting your Controller name, put in Route object

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new { Controller = "Subscriber", area = "area name here"}, null, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "ajaxBegin", OnFailure = "ajaxFailure", OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess" },new{id = "ajax1121"}){
}
```

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new { Controller = "Subscriber", Area = "Mail"}, new AjaxOptions..` still output `<form action="" ...` :(

Comment: Hmmmm, do you have a route registered for your area?

Comment: ohh, yes. Because I changed the default route, the one with `id = UrlParameter.Optional ` and `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Now I put it back now everything is working. Thanks